# Runtime exception during onWebsocketMessage: How can I read my JSON event data in Java with GSon?

Tags: java

I started learning Java 2 days ago, and I decided to start with my first challenge. I've almost got there but I am running into this exception I have shown below.

```
Runtime exception during onWebsocketMessage
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at com.eu.habbo.websockets.WebSocketEventHandler.handleEvent(WebSocketEventHandler.java:29)
        at com.eu.habbo.websockets.WebServer.onMessage(WebServer.java:35)
        at org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer.onWebsocketMessage(WebSocketServer.java:673)
        at org.java_websocket.drafts.Draft_6455.processFrameText(Draft_6455.java:885)
        at org.java_websocket.drafts.Draft_6455.processFrame(Draft_6455.java:819)
        at org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.decodeFrames(WebSocketImpl.java:379)
        at org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.decode(WebSocketImpl.java:216)
        at org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer$WebSocketWorker.doDecode(WebSocketServer.java:1046)
        at org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer$WebSocketWorker.run(WebSocketServer.java:1028)
An error occurred on connection /***.**.***.***:58016:java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Here is my code where I try and deserialize the JSON to a Java map.

Code: (WebSocketEventHandler's handleEvent method):

```
public void handleEvent(WebSocket socket, String eventJson) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Map<String, String> eventMap = gson.fromJson(eventJson, Map.class);

    String eventName = eventMap.get("event_name"); // line29
    String eventDataAsJson = eventMap.get("event_data");

    System.out.println("eventName: " + eventName);
    System.out.println("eventDataAsJson: " + eventDataAsJson);
}
```

Client code (JSON sent):

```
{
    'event_name': 'authenticate_with_sso',
    'event_data': {
        'sso_ticket': '**************'
    },
}
```

Comment: One of the `event_name` or `event_data` is not a string data. Based on the fields name the problem is on the `event_data`. Data:


`String eventDataAsJson = eventMap.get("event_data");`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a mapping POJO class to store your JSON parsed values.

try this code sample to parse your JSON data using Gson library

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
//To handle date data if there is any
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer());
ParsedObjectInfo info =gsonBuilder.create().fromJson(eventDataAsJson, ParsedObjectInfo.class);
```